# PHP Table Reader

Tags: php, html-table

How to read and get the ISP value from html table?

```
<table style="padding-top:10px;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<th>ISP:</th>
<td>My Provider</td>
</tr>   
<tr><th>Organization:</th><td nowrap=""></td>
</tr>                               
<tr><th>Connection:</th>
</tbody></table>
```

Comment: for ISP value are you refering to `My Provider`?, and if you generate the table using php you should had that value iin a variable, if not you have to use javascript

Comment: the table is here http://whatismyipaddress.com/ yes my provider is a ISP value

Answer (score 0):

Given you lack of information, a regular expression would be the easiest solution.

```
$matches = array();
preg_match("<th>ISP:</th>[\r\n\s\t]*<td>(.*)</td>", "<th>ISP:</th><td>My Provider</td>...", $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```